# Reason to use vector art instead of photos (How to convince a client one style is better than the other)

Tags: vector, client-relations, style, photography, art

**Context:** I did some vector art to use in a login page and adverts. I got cool reviews about it, but my boss prefers real photos instead of vector art. The photos and vector art are for a Business Intelligence/Finance corporate environment, and the subject is buildings and data.

**Problem:** I'm trying to sell this topic to my boss, but fruitlessly. I can't figure out a decent argument to present to choose vector art in detriment of photos.

In my opinion, this corporation needs more differentiating artwork and subject in the communication, because all of the pictures are stereotyped, standardized and cliché ([example](https://goo.gl/9D7VFI) [example 2](https://goo.gl/ICvqXg))

I would like to sell this idea to my boss; I think if I can show him a well explained point of view he will change his.

**Does anyone have the same point of view as me? How better could I present my argument?**

Artwork in question:

My concept for this, is to contrast with the heavy imagery website to present the user with a "smooth" transition between the website and the user interface were all the dashboards are presented.
[image]

Comment: Could you provide some examples of the vectors you're proposing as well as the images your boss suggests?

Comment: You might find [this question](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/50382/how-can-a-designer-explain-their-work-to-non-creative-people) helpful, especially SOIA's answer.

Comment: I'll provide the vector art in an edit Zach Saucier, the images he wants to use are demonstrated in example and in example 2
JTL thank you, this is very helpful as i'm not very fluent in explaining my point of view, and the questions also refers illustrations!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After years of working with clients and bosses I have learned to always ask, "Why?". For instance in your situation I would be asking, "What's the problem you are trying to solve with using a photograph?".

This does two things:

1. It reframes the question from design specifics to a language you both speak well
2. It reframes allows your boss to elaborate on his thought process

Speaking to the first point, talking to clients about color, imagery, etc. is typically not useful. They don't speak in design terms. They speak in business terms. I frame all my questions around problems I am solving for my clients and then interpret them into designs I sell back by going through their points, one by one, confirming why this is the right solution.

Speaking to the second point, maybe there is legitimately a reason why he wants a photograph over your vector image. Having him answer this question allows him to give you insight into a problem he doesn't think your vector image is solving. Breaking this down typically falls one of two ways. One, they realize there really was not good reason besides their personal preference, or second, they have a legitimate business reason for their argument and you can now solve that problem. If it was personal preference ask if this login page is for clients or for him/her? I think you can see where I am going with that.

The point of this is we are problem solvers. In every situation you can always go back to asking, "What is the problem I am trying to solve here?" A vector may be the best path to solving that problem. Maybe it'll be a different vector then the one you have created originally. Who knows? You will. After you ask why. =)

Hope this was helpful insight!

Comment: This is very helpful Frank, i'm a junior, and i lack this exact same experience, i will try to re-frame his thought and my own :) and i'll see the end experience of this. After that, i will make an update! Cheers

Comment: @Nunocruz Very good points from Frank. Some clients are stuck with the idea that concept pictures  are the best way to promote their message clearly and in a way, they do not trust their audience's intelligence. That's another point that can be used to show another perspective to clients. As Frank said, in the end it's possible it's a matter of preference and you might need to offer a solution that mixes pictures and flat art first, and then slowly bring the branding to something more elegant gradually. Sometimes you can't make "brutal" changes, some clients want to see themselves in your art!

Comment: I've been there Nunocruz. I am far enough long in my career that mentoring is something I genuinely enjoy. Again, it's common to try and speak the same language and the further you get in your career you'll understand that if your going to speak the same language, it's the language of business. =D

To @go-junta's point, client's sometimes have issues realize you are design for your clients and not them. At the end of the day, they pay the bills, but getting them to truly understand that fact will help both of your succeed in your goals.

Comment: Very good points there, this is exactly the feedback that i needed guys!
To make my problem worse, the company does not have a clear brand, and everything is made with no concept in mind and structure, with this imagery i'm trying to converge in one concept so i can show that we need to change the fact that we have no brand!
Thank's for all of you inputs it really helps me!!